# how to develop multi column treeview asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how to develop multi column treeview  asp.net 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You might have to create your own control extending GridView and TreeView. [Telerik's GridView](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) is very extensible and flexible and should be able to do it very easily but it's not free.